# Library design | Code organization for multiple developers

Tags: javascript

I've completed a personal project in a single file called Foo.js

The rest of my JavaScript I want to outsource, crowdsource, etc...

How do I organize?

I'm familiar with ANT ( build tool ) but want to do things manually at first w/ out any pre-processing.

Conceptually, how do you organize code from multiple people?

The final web-application will have one .js file.  If multiple files are used/needed(as part of the answer), they will be concatenated manually.

The application in encapsulated in an IIFE with the model, view, controller, and support modules implemented as objects in the local scope of the IIFE.

The pseudo-code is ( for main library / application file ) Foo.js

```
// Foo.js
(function(){
    var Mo = {},
        Vi = {},
        Co = {},
        Su = {};
})()
```

What I plan on doing currently is correlating each developer to a single .js file say...`user.js`

Pseudo-

```
// User.js
Mo.MyObject = {
}
Co.MyObject = {
}
.
.
```

Once all the code is completed....concatenate (using my own tool or manually), minify it, then compress it.

I'm not interested in using any tools or libraries currently.

I'm looking for info. on how to organize conceptually taking into account maintainability, robustness, and scalability.

Is this a good way to organize JavaScript for a web application?

Comment: Have a look at Google's Closure tools (library and compiler), maybe this is what you are after.

Comment: http://requirejs.org/ might also interest you.

Comment: I'm just asking for conceptual advice at the moment...not so much tools or libraries but the concepts of code organization in js...I have read/skimmed 5-10 books and have not come across this topic oddly.

Comment: Planning on just concatentaing it all inside the IIFE...and then minifiying...and then compresssing...does this sound reasonable?